# Animation washing text Blender Problem

Tags: animation

I'm using blender version 2.79b on windows 7. I have been unable to get the cracked text to wash off from the model. I followed all the instructions on the video tutorial. In the dynamic paint section, I have the water as the brush and the cracked text as the canvas. Also setup all the nodes in the compositing view. The only thing I can think of is that there may be a small bug with the attribute node.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, as I am trying to get this to work for a video presentation for Housekeeping Services.

Thanks

[image: This a photo of the model rendered at this time line]

The cracked text layer on the bottom of the HDMM up to the D, should have become clear at this point.

Comment: Hello Michael, I think what we need is some photos because its still a little unclear.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. No one can guess what is going on in your computer screen, so you need to make a bit more effort to explain.

Comment: pretty much what i just said, but yes.